# If there is a button in a link, when I click this button, how to avoid the link?

Tags: jquery

If there is a button in a link, when I click this button, how to avoid the link?

Comment: Why have you got a button in a link?

Answer (score 1):

You can just stop the propagation (event bubbling) with [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), like this:

```
$("a :button").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you have something like that:

```
<a ...>
    <button onclick="..."></button>
</a>
```

And you don't want to execute the link on the a-tag? You could write:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

But why you have a Button inside a link?

Comment: if there is a button in a link, when click the button , i want to disable the link but excute the buttun lick. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you add an `onclick="return false;"` to your link (I assume it's an anchor `<a>`), you can suppress navigation. Like so:

```
<a href="/gosomewhere.html" onclick="return false;">
    <button onclick="alert('no navigating!');">Button</button
</a>
```

No jQuery needed unless you can't change the link being generated.

Comment: This would prevent anything from using the link (why have it?) the `return false` behavior should be on the button instead.

Comment: but if I click other places except button, the link works

Comment: Well, the poster shouldn't have a button inside a link anyway...

Comment: @user525542 - see my answer above for how to do this, though you should really look at ordering your markup a different way.

Comment: like it or not, it is valid HTML, not saying *I* would do it, but there's nothing invalid here.